# Images not being loaded from gallery

Tags: android, image, picasso

> 

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 100);
 //on activity result now Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
Picasso.with(rootView.getContext()).load(selectedImageURI.toString()).into(image);
```

Okey simply, I call to open the gallery.Once opened i need to retrive image, its working in case of some pictures and in case of others not.
I noticed those others are images deleted from my phone? why are they showing?

ITS GIVing me uri content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1 ...its the -1 ones not working always. I do not get any crash either.

Comment: remove tostring
or post logcat

Comment: Images which are not showing is deleted programmatically or manually by you..?

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed those others are images deleted from my phone? why are they showing?

Because `MediaStore` does not know that the images were deleted, apparently. Whatever deleted them did not tell the `MediaStore` to update its index. Eventually, `MediaStore` will find this out and will filter them from its index, so the user cannot choose them via `ACTION_PICK`.

Comment: Programtically what solution i can use in my app? or just when user selects it...no images seen in place of imageview?

Comment: @Zenzen: I would just ignore it. You are welcome to scan the `Uri` and see if it fits your `-1` pattern, but I do not know how stable that is across Android OS versions and devices.